# Проверьте сочинение пожалуйста) сколько баллов?

Tags: оформление-текста

Проверьте пожалуйста сочинение ЕГЭ)на сколько балов тянет?

(1)Чего же ты, Боже, мне крыльев не дал,
Я б Землю покинул и в небо взлетал...
(Тарас Шевченко)

(2)Одной из загадок в истории существования всего живого на Земле является появление крылатых насекомых. (3)В летописи окаменелостей они начинают фигурировать примерно 300 миллионов лет назад (в отличие от обычных насекомых — 435-410 миллионов).

(4)Убелённые сединами приверженцы эволюционной теории не без затруднения и не очень складно объясняют процесс развития крыльев у насекомых, их волшебные летательные возможности. (5)К чему это я?

(6)А к тому, что человек издавна устремлял свой тоскующий взгляд на всё, что могло легко и запросто летать, кружить и порхать над его головой. (7) Оттого-то с древних времён он строил, склеивал, сколачивал и собирал немыслимые конструкции и приспособления для собственного воспарения.

(8)И в самом деле, следя за невероятными кульбитами ласточек и стрижей над речной волной, наблюдая за фантастическими пируэтами гоняющихся за мошкарой стрекоз или, скажем, ловко вальсирующей меж цветками куста шиповника пчелы, мы, признаемся, нередко с восхищением вопрошаем: неужели такое возможно? (9)Какое же это чудо! (10)Вот бы и нам, людям, так! (И)Однако ж, увы... а ведь считается, что человек — вершина эволюции! (12)Ну, или Божьего замысла...

(13)Нет, конечно, человечество научилось летать на монгольфьерах, самолётах, вертолётах и ракетах, но этого ему, очевидно, мало.

(14)    Человеку хочется именно ЛЕТАТЬ так, как это делают птицы, мотыльки, жуки, стрекозы! (15)Но подвластно ли сие «рождённому ползать»?

(16)Одним из первых, кто в этом смысле бросил вызов и природе, и высшему разуму, был великий Леонардо да Винчи. (17)Его несколько блестящих проектов «орнитоптеров» и других летательных машин, в том числе и вертолёта, и парашюта, опередили его время и, безусловно, дали благотворный импульс для развития авиации, а также летательных возможностей человека.

(18)Впрочем,    Леонардо не был бы великим, если бы всё-таки не понял тщету своих усилий в разработке подвижного крыла, работающего только лишь при помощи человеческой мускулатуры.

(19)    Так что вернуться к махолётам неугомонные мечтатели и безумцы смогли лишь в двадцатом веке, когда появились сравнительно компактные энергетические и силовые установки. (20)Между тем о перемещениях человека в воздушном пространстве без помощи сложных устройств разговоры идут давно, например, о левитации — перемещении человека во времени и пространстве.(21) К месту здесь будет вспомнить и танцы мистиков — дервишей, умеющих во время своихневероятных кружений взлетать к божественному миру и Богу, а затем возвращаться на землю.

(22)Так сможет ли человек, уповая даже на самые современные достижения науки, техники и прогресса, летать, как птица или насекомое? (23)Вопрос сложный...

(24)А может быть, он, человек, не там ищет? (25)Прислушаемся к любопытным замечаниям некоторых учёных и исследователей, которые резюмируют, что эволюция крылатых насекомых есть тайна, не имеющая объяснения. (26)Что их появление было внезапно и что самые древние экземпляры имеют ту же структуру, что и их родственники, живущие в XXI веке. (27)Что летопись окаменелостей указывает на то, что их сложное эволюционное продвижение (если оно было) произошло так быстро, что данный факт противоречит собственно эволюционной теории... (28)Что всё было однажды сделано полностью функциональным с самого начала. (29)Что, наконец, «все свидетельства указывают на РАЗУМНЫЙ дизайн полёта насекомых — его форму, функцию и создание».

(ЗО)Так полетим мы, как ОНИ? (31) Думаю, полетим. (32)С одним условием: ежели это будет угодно самим НЕБЕСАМ...

(По Г. Рогову)
 Сможет ли человек научиться летать, как птицы и крылатые насекомые? Именно над этим вопросом размышляет Г. Рогов в своем тексте. Автор говорит о том, что человек всегда смотрел на летающих существ и мечтал так же парить в воздухе. Он пытался полететь с помощью каких-либо приспособлений и смог, но, видимо, человечеству этого мало: люди хотели летать сами, без подручных средств.
 Г. Рогов считает, что многие хотят летать, но мы полетим, как птицы только "с одним условием: ежели это будет угодно самим небесам".
 Я согласна с мнением автора в том, что человек не может летать сам по себе. Если такой полет и произойдет, то он случится неожиданно, по повелению высшего разума. В пьесе А. Н. Островского "Гроза" главная героиня хотела на свободу. Катерина задавалась вопросом-от чего люди не летают, как птицы?
 Конечно, и мне бы хотелось летать. Наверное, это мечта каждого ребенка. В наше время, на мой взгляд, самым доступный, похожий на полет крылатых насекомых, является полет в аэротрубе. Там человек ощущает невесомость, и если закрыть глаза, то можно представить, как ты летишь над городом, сам.
 Итак, можно сказать, что человечество достигло многого. Мы можем летать на самолетах, парапланах, в аэротрубе, но сам, без подручных средств, человек полетит, если этого захотят высшие силы.

Comment: Просто для инфы. "Чего же ты, Боже, мне крыльев не дал? Я б Землю покинул и в небо взлетал..." — Шевченко такого не говорил. Это из стихов [Михаила Петренко](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Петренко,_Михаил_Николаевич).

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся.

Answer (score 1):

Содержание неплохое. Всего 16 баллов из 23.

Сод.-6б.-по высшей(1-2-1-3). Но литерат. аргумент могут не принять, потому что произведение названо, но мысль не доведена до конца, не сказано, что мечта Катерины так и осталась мечтой, в переносном смысле тоже,законы Домостроя "подрезали крылья",свободную птицу "заперли"в 4 стенах.

Реч.оформл.1 балл(К5-0(нет абзацного членения текста);К6-1)

Грамотность-9б. (2б.+2б.+1б.+2б.+1б.+1б.)-

Орф.ош.-1 - отчего(почему - наречие, слитно) люди не летают, как птицы?
пунктуац. ош.-2 - полетим как птицы-нет запятой (полетим птицей)

Катерина задавалась вопросом:(поясняет, раскрывает смысл)

Грамм. ош.-1--самым доступный, похожий на полет крылатых насекомых, является полет

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!